Google OAuth consent screen
Getting an issue when trying to set up my consent screen the error says
Make sure your home page includes a link to your privacy policy.
It does but the website is written in flutter so it is canvas kit and js, i tried using the html renderer but it didnt work either, can someone confirm that im doing this right?
site is www.sealstudios.co.uk
privacy policy is www.sealstudios.co.uk/#/privacy_policy
from what i understood this should work but since its flutter and i think the verification is automated it cant find the button in the html because it doesnt exist there not sure what to do

Added a form button to my html as I'm sure the verification is automated but it didn't work
